# BibLaTeX isn't writing out bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber, texstudio

I'm using the following in my main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=140mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}


\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none,backend=biber,maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{danish}{andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

In my references.bib file I have:

```
@article{edwards,
    author        = {N. Edwards, P.},
    title         = {History of climate modeling},
    journaltitle  = {WIREs Clim Change},
    year          = {2011},
    volume        = {2},
    pages         = {128--139},
    doi           = {10.1002/wcc.95}
}

@article{flato,
    author        = {M. Flato, G.},
    title         = {Earth system models: an overview},
    journaltitle  = {WIREs Clim Change},
    year          = {2011},
    volume        = {2},
    pages         = {783--800},
    doi           = {10.1002/wcc.148}
}

@incollection{heymann,
    author    = {Heymann, M. and Sandøe, P. and Andersen, H.},
    title     = {What is climate science all about? Philosophical perspectives},
    booktitle = {Jorden Brænder},
    editor    = {Gjerris, M. and Gamborg, C. and Olesen, J.E. and Wolf, J.},
    publisher = {Forlaget Alfa},
    address   = {Frederiksberg},
    year      = {2009},
    pages     = {65--67}
}

@incollection{heymann2,
    author    = {Heymann, M.},
    title     = {Climate science – how did it come about?},
    booktitle = {Jorden Brænder},
    editor    = {Gjerris, M. and Gamborg, C. and Olesen, J.E. and Wolf, J.},
    publisher = {Forlaget Alfa},
    address   = {Frederiksberg},
    year      = {2009},
    pages     = {69--87}
}

@incollection{IPCC,
    author    = {Le Treut, H. and Somerville, R. and Cubasch, U. and Ding, Y. and Mauritzen, C. and Mokssit, A. and Peterson, T. and Prather, M.},
    title     = {Historical Overview of Climate Change},
    booktitle = {Climate Change 2007: The Physical Science Basis. Contribution of Working Group I to the Fourth Assessment Report
    of the Intergovernmental Panel on Climate Change},
    editor    = {Solomon, S. and Qin, D. and Manning, M. and Chen, Z. and Marquis, M. and Averyt, K.B. and Tignor, M. and Miller, H.L.},
    publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    address   = {Cambridge, United Kingdom and New York, NY, USA},
    year      = {2007},
    pages     = {95--122}
}
```

And at the bottom of my main.tex file I have:

```
\nocite{*}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

When I Build & View my main.tex I get no errors, but still, the bibliography isn't being printed. I do get some warning at the line where \printbibliography is, that says:

```
Empty bibliography

There were undefined references.

Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) main(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

I'm am using the latest version of TeXstudio, and up until recently, I have actually been able to get the bibliography printed.

I'm not entirely sure how to "(re)run Biber..." as it says in the warning, but I have cleaned all aux files, tried to restart TeXstudio and so forth.

So what am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Build and View is the compiler, or whatever it is called, in TeXstudio.
The commandline I use for that is: txs:///pdflatex | txs:///biber | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf

Comment: I don't think it is TeXstudio.
I have tried to run it in ShareLatex, and there I get the same. The document is compiled, but the bibliography is not shown.

Comment: That should be the case.
It does run biber, and if I'm not mistaken, sharelatex should take care of that compared to editors. And even there it does not work :/

Comment: Okay.
This might be a stupid question, but how do I do what you say ? I'm pretty new to LaTeX, so I have no idea how to "command line" stuff and such :/

Comment: I'm Using Win 8.1.
But when I do that, it says:

"'biber' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

Or, I can run the first command (pdflatex), but the second command, I get the above error.

Comment: Do you have `biber` installed?  If not, get it from here: [http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/).  I'm  not sure if MikTeX comes with it or not.  (I'm on Linux, and I last used MikTeX before `biber` even existed, unfortunately.)

Comment: I think so.
Even after I downloaded the .exe file from the link you have given, and of course run the .exe file, I get the same result :/

Comment: OK, I recommend editing the question to reflect the source of the error.  It seems as though it is a question about getting Biber to work on your platform, which is not something I'm qualified to help you with.  Once you get Biber up and running, your file should work just fine.  I'm going to delete my other comments since they are directed to a different problem.

Comment: What exactly happens if you run `biber main`, do you get any output: warnings errors etc.? Or you you still get ` 'biber' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. In that case try to add the directory `biber` is in to the `PATH` so Windows can find it (or start `biber` explicitly).